# How can I edit a vue.js app without restart the server with npm run dev

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

How can I edit a vue app without using *npm run dev* after every change on my components?
Is this even possible, like in the Laravel Framework with the *php artisan serve* command?

I'm using the WSL on a Windows 10 machine for using npm.

Comment: npm run watch??

Comment: I was also testing 'npm run watch' with different settings but with Laravel and inertia.js, was the only way that was working fine for me 'npm run watch-poll'

Answer (score 0):

HMR is the default behaviour of most bundlers.

Vite:
https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#hot-module-replacement

Webpack:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/